# Python numpy uint64 gets converted to float on division

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, python-2.x

I wanted to do a simple integer division e.g. `1/3=0`, but `uint64` behaves very weirdly, resulting in my result being casted to float. Why?

```
python> uint64(100)/3
Out[0]: 33.333333333333336
python> uint64(100)/uint64(3)
Out[1]: 33
python> int64(100)/3
Out[2]: 33
python> int64(100)/uint64(3)
Out[3]: 33.333333333333336
python> int32(100)/int64(3)
Out[4]: 33
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because Python sees a signed and an unsigned type and tries to automatically deduce the result type, which will be signed. But as the first 64-bit number was unsigned the signed version would need 65-bit. As there is no integer type in Python/Numpy higher than 64 bit, Python chooses `float64`. The standard type i.e. for the divisor `3` is `int64`, that's why the first example will be cast to `float64`. 
This also works with multplications of course:

```
python> import numpy as np
python> type( np.int64( 10 ) * np.int64( 1 ) )
Out[0]: numpy.int64
python> type( np.uint64( 10 ) * np.uint64( 1 ) )
Out[1]: numpy.uint64
python> type( np.uint64( 10 ) * np.int64( 1 ) )
Out[2]: numpy.float64
```

Note that this automatic type deduction only applies to different signed types, because it is value agnostic, else almost all types would have to end up as `float64`, because e.g. after three consecutive multiplications it could be possible that it doesn't fit into `uint64` anymore.

```
type(uint64(12345678900)*uint64(12345678900))
/usr/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ulong_scalars
#! /usr/bin/python
Out[3]: numpy.uint64
```

Note: Beware that in Python 3 the simple slash is the integer division by default anymore. Instead you would have to use `3 // 2` to get `1` as `3 / 2 == 1.5` in Python 3.

Comment: Huh. I've seen a related problem with the bitwise operators, but there, it's just a TypeError because NumPy doesn't consider floating-point result types an option. I didn't think they'd go for floating-point output on non-bitwise operations. On 1.8.1, I get a floating-point output for that mixed-signedness multiplication; what NumPy version are you on?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm using Python 2.7.11 and Numpy 1.11.0